# having error while using square bracket in php

Tags: php, apache

I am unsetting the session variable by

```
    $_SESSION = [];
```

this is working fine in my localhost apache server. but when i deployed my website  **[www.mobi3.pe.hu](http://mobi3.pe.hu)**  I get the error

```
       Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/u832047490/includes/functions.php on line 36
```

which is this line only

```
         $_SESSION = [];
```

and this is not only the error if I coment it. I used a function and when return an associative array by

```
     return [
        "symbol" => $data[0],
        "name" => $data[1],
        "price" => $data[2],
    ];
```

I get the error

```
   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/u832047490/includes/functions.php on line 91
```

which is the line I mentioned earlier.

can't figure out why is this happening with square bracket. and this is happening everywhere it encounter's "[ ".. would really appreciate if one's figure out..

Comment: `$_SESSION = [];` allowed in php.5.4, for older versions use `$_SESSION = array();`

Comment: Probably the different PHP versions. Use `$_SESSION = array();`

Comment: @u_mulder Too funny how we both think alike lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short array syntax [was introduced in PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php), and your hoster hasn't upgraded yet.

Run `phpinfo();` to see which version is currently running.

If you need to backport your code, you can use `array(...)` instead, as in:

```
return array("symbol" => $data[0], "name" => $data[1], "price" => $data[2]);
```

This is just the 'old way' of doing things.

It is also quite a good idea to kick your hoster about upgrading, since [PHP 5.3 is already in its end-of-life cycle](http://php.net/releases/5_3_20.php) since nearly 2 years.

Comment: Have a +1. PHP 5.3 is actually even **out** of its end-of-life cycle now - it was fully EOLed four months ago. http://php.net/eol.php

Comment: Same to you - I thought it was still in 'critical fixes only'  :)  Learn something every day.